# How can i make the hover on an pseudo element do not affect the parent?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

So I have this parent which has an :after pesudo-element. When that parent is hover it changes its background color, it does the same if the :after is hovered and i don't want this. Can someone tell me how can i make that background be changed only if it's parent is hovered, not on that :after? Can someone help me ?
I've been trying this whole day. 
Thanks :)

P.S. I'm working on a table and i can't modify the sizes..  I am using. I can use html/css and javascript/jquery.

Comment: using jquery add `.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling up to parent